# How to make the z-color of a contour plot mapped on the line?

Tags: plotting

Ideal picture effect:

[image]
$$
z=\frac{\frac{u}{1-u}K_{1/3}\left( \frac{u}{3\left( 1-u \right)} \right) +S\cdot \text{Int}\left( u \right) -S\frac{u^2-2u+2}{1-u}K_{2/3}\left( \frac{u}{3\left( 1-u \right)} \right)}{S\cdot u\cdot K_{1/3}\left( \frac{u}{3\left( 1-u \right)} \right) -\left( 2K_{2/3}\left( \frac{u}{3\left( 1-u \right)} \right) -\text{Int}\left( u \right) \right)}
$$
$$
\text{Int}\left( u \right) =\int_{\frac{u}{3\left( 1-u \right)}}^{\infty}{K_{1/3}\left( a \right)}\text{da}
$$
where $K$ is the second class of modified Bessel functions.

```
Int[u_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[BesselK[1/3, a], {a, u/(3 (1 - u)), Infinity}];
ContourPlot[(
 u/(1 - u) BesselK[1/3, u/(3 (1 - u))] + S  Int[u] - 
  S (u^2 - 2 u + 2)/(1 - u) BesselK[2/3, u/(3 (1 - u))])/(
 S  u BesselK[1/3, u/(3 (1 - u))] - (2 BesselK[2/3, u/(3 (1 - u))] - 
    Int[u])), {u, 0, 0.99}, {S, -1, 1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

Resulting figure:

[image]

Comment: As stated in the documentation, you can get a continuous scale with `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, None]`.

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what I think the point is to have the `BarLegend` colours shown in the contour lines without the filling, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Int[u_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[BesselK[1/3, a],
   {a, u/(3 (1 - u)), Infinity}];

z[u_, S_] = (u/(1 - u) BesselK[1/3, u/(3 (1 - u))] + S Int[u] -
     S (u^2 - 2 u + 2)/(1 - u) BesselK[2/3, u/(3 (1 - u))])/
   (S u BesselK[1/3, u/(3 (1 - u))] -
     (2 BesselK[2/3, u/(3 (1 - u))] - Int[u]));

{zmin, zmax} = {-1, 1};

contours = Subdivide[zmin, zmax, 10];

styles = 
 Blend[{Blue, LightBlue, Red}, #] & /@ (Rescale[#, {zmin, zmax}] & /@ 
    contours)
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[z[u, S],
 {u, 0, 0.99}, {S, -1, 1},
 Contours -> contours,
 ContourStyle ->
  (Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], #] & /@
    styles),
 ContourShading -> None,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@
    {HoldForm[u], HoldForm[S]}),
 RotateLabel -> False,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   BarLegend[{Blend[{Blue, LightBlue, Red}, #] &,
     {zmin, zmax}},
    LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm[z], 14],
    LegendMarkerSize -> 360], Above]]
```

[image]